# Image is not displayed when I use jpeg format its not working - swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

```
 var pet = ["dog","cat" ,"rabbit"]
```

> Here pet[myindex] not working please help!

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TitleLabel.text=pet[myindex]
        DescLabel.text=petdesc[myindex]
        myImage.image=UIImage(named : (pet[myindex] + ". jpeg"))

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is it crashing? Is there an error?

Comment: pet[myindex]  is not working . if i write cat.japg insted of pet[myindex] then its working !

Comment: Yes. You said it is "not working" is it just not doing anything? Is it crashing? Is there an error? What is the value of `myIndex`? There is a lot of ways something can "not work". Just trying to understand what is happening. :-) have you tried making the string before hand to check it is definitely what you think it is? Also, are you using asset catalogs?

Comment: var myindex=0 i have use assets catelog ! pet[myindex] value is not printing and then image is not diplay !

Comment: If you're using asset catalogs then you don't need the ".jpeg". You're loading the asset, not the image file. Let the asset catalog sort out the file stuff. In the asset catalog look at the name listed there and use that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have put an additional space in the `". jpeg"`. That should not be there. Delete it like this...

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TitleLabel.text=pet[myindex]
    DescLabel.text=petdesc[myindex]
    myImage.image=UIImage(named : (pet[myindex] + ".jpeg")) // removed the space here

}
```

Comment: You haven't changed anything. If you have, explain the change you made.

Comment: Then put that in your answer. I shouldn't have to "look carefully" at an answer to work out what has changed. It's not spot the difference. If you change something, explain what you changed and why. Otherwise it's not an answer.

Comment: @kairashah it works but you're still bypassing he asset catalog. Just delete the whole jpeg part and use the name.

Comment: @AbhishekJain edited. Do you see how that is much easier to understand now?